# the operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

at line 40:
if(stringArray[j] > stringArray[j+1])

it says the operator > is undefined for the argument types java.lang.String, java.lang.String. Why? and how do i fix it?

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome! How many strings would you like to sort?");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int stringSize = input.nextInt();
        String [] array = new String[stringSize];           //creating array of the inputed size

        for (int i = 0; i < stringSize; i++)                //loop for iterating array
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter string " + (i+1) + ": ");
            String stringInput = input.next();      //entering strings
            array[i] = stringInput;                         //assigning to corresponding locations
        }

        int arrayLength = array.length;
        sortLength(array, arrayLength);
        System.out.print("Your sorted array is: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) 
            System.out.println(array[i] + ", "); 

        input.close();
        System.out.print("Goodbye!");
    }

    public static void sortLength(String [] stringArray, int length) //sorting from shortest to longest using bubblesort method
    {
        length = stringArray.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)             //i represents # of items sorted
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                String temp = stringArray[i];
                if(stringArray[j] > stringArray[j+1])   //comparing and swapping the array elements
                {
                    temp = stringArray[j];
                    stringArray[j] = stringArray[j+1];
                    stringArray[j+1] = temp;
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `stringArray[j].compareTo( stringArray[j+1] ) > 0` Sorry, welcome to Java.

Answer (score 2):

> It says the operator > is undefined for the argument types java.lang.String, java.lang.String.

Correct

> Why?

Because the relational operators `>`, `>=`, `<` and `<=` are only defined for primitive types.  `String` is not a primitive type.  It is a reference type.

(Aside: the `==` and `!=` operators are defined for reference types, but you should not use them for comparing `String` values.  Use `String::equals` for that.  See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java))

> And how do i fix it?

It depends on what you are trying to do:

- If you are trying to compare two `String` values lexically, use `String::compareTo` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-))
- If you are trying to compare two `String` values lexically ignoring lower / uppercase distinctions, use `String::compareToIgnoreCase` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-)).
- If you are trying to order `String` objects by length, you will need to implement this by comparing values returned by `String::length` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length--)).  (You may want / need to use `String::compareTo` as a tie-breaker for when you have two strings that are the same length but not equal.  Read your exercise's requirements carefully.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the `length` of the array in as an argument, and you should actually call [`String.length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length--) to get (and compare by) the length(s) of your `String`(s). Also, don't just compare adjacent elements with `j` and `j+1` (use `i`). Like,

```
public static void sortLength(String[] stringArray) {
    for(int i = 1; i < stringArray.length; i++)            
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if(stringArray[j].length() > stringArray[i].length())
            {
                String temp = stringArray[j];
                stringArray[j] = stringArray[i];
                stringArray[i] = temp;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```